# Jackson JSON java class - fields are serialized multiple times

Tags: java, android, json, jackson, resttemplate

I have a following class defined

```
@JsonTypeName("PhotoSetUpdater")
public class PhotoSetUpdater {
@JsonProperty("Title")
private String title;
@JsonProperty("Caption")
private String caption;
@JsonProperty("Keywords")
private String[] keywords;
@JsonProperty("Categories")
private int[] categories;
@JsonProperty("CustomReference")
    private String customReference;      // new in version 1.1


public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getCaption() {
    return caption;
}

public void setCaption(String caption) {
    this.caption = caption;
}


public String getCustomReference() {
    return customReference;
}


public void setCustomReference(String customReference) {
    this.customReference = customReference;
}


public void setKeywords(String[] keywords) {
    this.keywords = keywords;
}

public String[] getKeywords() {
    return keywords;
}


public void setCategories(int[] categories) {
    this.categories = categories;
}


public int[] getCategories() {
    return categories;
}
```

}

The problem is that after I serialize this class with Jackson JSON serializer, the fields are insetrted twice in the result payload: one starting with lower letter, one with capital letter:

... {"Caption":"aa","caption":"aa",...}

What may be wrong with type definition?

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `@JsonAutoDetect(getterVisibility=Visibility.NONE)` on the class.

Comment: This works -- alternatively you could have just added @JsonProperty on getter; although with 1.8 and earlier this leads to duplication (needs to be on both getter and setter). Jackson 1.9 will (finally!) merge annotations, so adding that to just getter would work for both getter and setter.